# gcc without g++?

Tags: 13.04, gcc, g++

I run Ubuntu 13.04 (`x86_64` if it matters) which I recently installed. Before, when using 12.10, I had both `gcc` and `g++` from the beginning. However, with 13.04 after I downloaded `gcc-4.8.1` sources I found out I was not able to build it due to lack of a C++ compiler. I tried `g++` in console and it said the program was not installed. `gcc -v` shows `c++` among other languages in `--enable-languages`.

So, the question basically is: how come `gcc` package does not contain the C++ compiler (`g++`)? I know (well, at least I guess) I can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get intall g++
```

but I wonder if I can somehow make my pre-installed `gcc` package work. Maybe linking `gcc` to `g++` or something? I am pretty sure with Ubuntu 12.10 I had `g++` from the beginning.

Comment: Why not just install `build-essential`?  It will allow you to make all this work without any other hassle.  Also, `gcc` is the C compiler not the C++ compiler, so you have to use `g++` for C++

Comment: Read [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/172592/2530240). It clarifies why `g++` depends on `gcc` and not backwards.

Comment: Yes but `gcc` (standing for GNU Compiler Collection) should *contain* c++ compiler (`g++`). In other words, `g++` is supposed to be part of `gcc` package (wiki agrees).

Comment: Yes, but it is not a *strict* dependency. You can have a C compiler without needing a C++ one. In the end, whether `g++` comes with `gcc` is up to the package maintainers. Notice that not having `g++` as a dependency makes of `gcc` a lighter package to install (not just in download size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc and g++(gcc for C, g++ for C++, etc.) are driver programs(very often they are distributed as seperate packages thus installing one does not guarantee another) which 
users invoke. They interprets command arguments, calls the actual compiler, runs the assembler on the output, and then optionally runs the linker to produce a complete executable binary.

More read and refs:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/gcc-defaults